# fscanf doesnot work in file pointer array

Tags: c

I am making a program to read data from multiple files in a loop but fscanf function seems to not behave the way it should.

```
fscanf(fptr, "%d,%d", &x[0], &y[0]);
```

This code works if fptr is a normal file pointer i.e. FILE *fptr.

```
fscanf(fptr[0], "%d,%d", &x[0], &y[0]);
```

This code does NOT work if fptr is a file pointer array i.e. FILE *fptr[2].

SO, my program looks like this.

```
int x[50];
int y[50];
FILE *fptr[2];
FILE *fptrr;
fptr[0] = fopen("datasets/datasetLR1.txt", "r");
fptr[1] = fopen("datasets/datasetLR2.txt", "r");
fptrr = fopen("datasets/datasetLR2.txt", "r");

 int index = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fptrr, "%d,%d", &x[index], &y[index]);
            //This works (as in puts data correctly in the array)

            fscanf(fptr[i], "%d,%d", &x[index], &y[index]);
            //This does not work (as in every entry in the array is a zero)

            printf("%d,%d ", x[index], y[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you initialize `fptr[0]`? The problem likely lies in the code not shown. Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. The shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  Post is edited.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Check out the updated post.

Comment: @JHBonarius Its C. Is file handling not similar in C and C++?

Comment: The edit still needs approving??? can the OPs no longer edit their own posts?

Comment: In the edit that I cannot see, the same file is opened twice.

Comment: @Surt OP is using two accounts? Tempacc looks a lot like "temporary account". Person to edit is rsnpj.

Comment: Yes, C++ has standardized improved ways for file handling.

Comment: @Surt I don't think that's the problem because  fscanf(fptr[0], "%d,%d", &x[0], &y[0]); Even this doesnot work if I comment out all the loops.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes I am using multiple account as my main account is banned for asking questions for whatever reasons :(

Comment: Does the file `"datasets/datasetLR1.txt"` actually exist? `fptr[0]` and `fptrr` are handles to different files. Perhaps one could be opened successfully and the other failed, so `fptr[0]` is simply null.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It does exist. No problem on file. No problem on loops. Just the part I have highlighted causes trouble.

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference whether a `FILE*` value is stored in a standalone variable, or in an element of an array. You are chasing a red herring; to the extent there is a problem, it lies elsewhere. By concentrating on `fptrr` vs `fptr[0]`, you are wasting valuable time. That's why it's important to show a [mcve] and not what your program "looks like" - chances are high you are omitting the actual problematic parts  by deeming them irrelevant.

Comment: What is `i` when the error occures?

Comment: I just compiled an ran the sample and I see no issues there - in your example you are assigning values to x[index] and y[index] twice - once from fptrr and once from fptr[i] but otherwise check if there is something wrong with the file contents and if they were opened correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After each `fopen` you need to check for correctness.

```
if (file == nullptr) {
  perror("The error: ");
  // handle error
}
```

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) for another example.

After each fscanf you should check the return value and handle errors.

```
if (2 != fscanf(fptr[i], "%d,%d", &x[index], &y[index])) {
  perror("The error : ");
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: I did do that. No errors were found. Still the same problem.

Comment: @rsnpj Your posted code shows zero error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the following and check the output for errors. Additionally try using full path for the filenames and make sure that they have at least 10 rows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[]){
  int x[50];
  int y[50];
  FILE *fptr[2];
  fptr[0] = fopen("datasets/datasetLR1.txt", "r");
  fptr[1] = fopen("datasets/datasetLR2.txt", "r");

  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)  {
    if (fptr[i] == NULL){
      printf("file %i is not opened\n",i);
      continue;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      if(fscanf(fptr[i], "%d,%d", &x[index], &y[index])==2){
        printf("File: %i; Row: %i; Index: %i; x: %d; y: %d\n",i,j,index,x[index], y[index]);
      }
      else {
        printf("Wrong data at file: %i; Row: %i; Index: %i; x: %d; y: %d\n",i,j,index,x[index], y[index]);
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    fclose(fptr[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```